# jogl java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: with gluegen-rt.dll

Tags: java, jogl

I have just been introduced to `Java` and `JOGL` for a university course. 
I am trying to set up a development environment but I am running into several difficulties.

Whenever I try to run any `JOGL` application I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
C:\Users\user>\AppData\Local\Temp\jogamp_0000\file_cache\jln8888451586118307843\jln8967240096003338483\gluegen-rt.dll: 
Access is denied
```

I get this for every project I create, every demo project I try to run and demo applications that I try to run just to have a look at what they do.

I can see that this is a permission problem. What I don't understand is this:

1. Why is the gluegen-rt.dll being extracted to here?
2. Why are there permissions to create this file but not to read from it?

At the moment my projects are using the native JARs, but if someone can link me to a tutorial on how to use the native libraries instead that would be appreciated.

I am running on `Windows 8 x64` with `jre7` and using `JOGL 2.0`.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by your virus scanner (F-Secure, Microsoft Security Essentials, ...).

This is a false positive or a real virus infected your machine and modified several DLLs used by `GlueGen` and `JOGL`.

`GlueGen` extracts the native libraries from JARs and copy them into a temporary directory in order to load them, they can't be loaded directly from JARs.

Using the native libraries without those JARs won't solve the problem if the virus scanner still considers that they are dangerous.

Edit.: It can be caused by a conflict with Maven. I remember that a developer had a similar problem a few weeks ago. It went away after clearing Maven's cache in the .m2 directory.